# How to make bar3d plot with transparent faces and non-transparent edges?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Code that draws consecutive 3d bar plots with varying `alpha` parameter

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

for i, alpha in enumerate([1.0, 0.5, 0.1, 0.01]):
    fig = plt.figure()
    fig.suptitle('alpha is ' + str(alpha))
    axes = fig.gca(projection='3d')
    axes.bar3d(
        0, 0, 0., 1., 1., 1.,
        alpha=alpha,
        edgecolor='black')
    # plt.show()
    fig.savefig('facecolor_'+str(i)+'.png')
```

Outcomes

[image: alpha is 1.0]
[image: alpha is 0.5]
[image: alpha is 0.1]
[image: alpha is 0.01]

As you can see, the bar almost completely vanishes, both faces and edges become invisible as `alpha` tends to `0.0`. What I would like to achieve is to have faces vanish but keep the edges, the expected result would be something like this:

[image: expected result]

The use case for that is sometimes you plot nested bars inside of bars as reference value and you wouldn't want the faces of outer bars cover faces of nested bars.

Anyone has an idea? Is that even possible with Matplotlib or am I wasting my time and I should just switch to different plotting library? If that's the case maybe someone could recommend a better tool? I know Matpotlib is not too proud of their 3D plots and officially advertises itsels as 2D plotting library.

Environment used to generate those plots is

```
$ sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.14.5
BuildVersion:   18F132
```

Python version

```
$ python -V
Python 3.7.4
```

Matplotlib version

```
$ pip show matplotlib
Name: matplotlib
Version: 3.1.2
Summary: Python plotting package
Home-page: https://matplotlib.org
Author: John D. Hunter, Michael Droettboom
Author-email: matplotlib-users@python.org
License: PSF
Location: /Users/marek/.pyenv/versions/3.7.4/lib/python3.7/site-packages
Requires: kiwisolver, pyparsing, numpy, python-dateutil, cycler
Required-by:
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try

```
fig = plt.figure()
fig.suptitle('alpha is ' + str(0.1))
axes = fig.gca(projection='3d')
axes.bar3d(
    0, 0, 0., 1., 1., 1.,
    color=(0, 0, 1, 0),
    edgecolor='black')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating further on @abhilb's answer. If you want to give the cube some controled color with some transparency while keeping the edges solid, you can try:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import colors
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

for i, alpha in enumerate([1.0, 0.5, 0.1, 0.01]):
    fig = plt.figure()
    fig.suptitle('alpha is ' + str(alpha))
    axes = fig.gca(projection='3d')
    color = 'dodgerblue'
    rgb = colors.colorConverter.to_rgb(color)
    rgba = rgb + (alpha,)
    axes.bar3d(
        0, 0, 0., 1., 1., 1.,
        color=rgba,
        edgecolor='black')
    plt.show()
```

[image: sample plot]